# Can't get stuff to save after refresh

Tags: html

Me and a friend are trying to make a site to help you organize stuff such as homework, we are both kinda new to programming, but we know some basics. We are having trouble having stuff save when you drag text from one box to the other, so when I refresh the page, the text isn't in the box i dragged it to.

Here is our current html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<html>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/HomeworkOrganizer123.html">Homework Orgnaizer</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="">Features</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link disabled" href="">Disabled</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
    </header>
<head>
    <style>
        #div1{
          float: left;
          width: 500px;
          height: 400px;
          margin: 20px;
          padding: 10px;
          border: 2px solid black;
        }
        #div2{
          float: right;
          width: 500px;
          height: 400px;
          margin: 20px;
          padding: 10px;
          border: 2px solid black;
        }
        </style>
        <script>
        function allowDrop(ev) {
          ev.preventDefault();
        }
        
        function drag(ev) {
          ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
        }
        
        function drop(ev) {
          ev.preventDefault();
          var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
          ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }
        
        </script>
</head>
<body>


<!--sdfjoasdlf;jasdfl-->
<h1 style="text-align: center; padding-top: 15px;">Homework For 9/14-9/18</h1>
<h2 style="float: left; padding-left: 200px;">To-Do</h2>
<h2 style="text-align: right; padding-right: 200px">Completed</h2>

<div id='page' style='width: 300px'>
<p draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1"><span style='padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 4px; border: 2px black solid;'>test15757qweqwr qwre</p>
</div>
<p draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2"><span style='padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 4px; border: 2px black solid;'>test15757qweqwr qwre</p>
</div>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  </div>
  
  <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please post whatever code you've tried / are working with. Refreshing page will always reload the html from where ever it's served from. You may need to post to the server and save the value....

Comment: Welcome to SO. Like @MosheSommers suggests, please post code samples and identify exactly where you are stuck and what it is we can help with. Also, maybe try to use more specific wording than "stuff".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really vague since we have no clue on how you are building this. Perhaps it's a good idea to be more specific and -even more so- to read up on server-side data storage (or local html5 storage if the data is relatively little).

Edit; As you've now added code this clears it up a bit.
The problem is quite simple: A browser reload clears all input from input fields (some settings or extensions can bypass that but never mind those edge cases).

The solution is a bit more complex. You can either store the entered data on a server, like a database, and attach a session/cookie to the data. You could also look into HTML5 local storage so you don't need to hook up a database.

What also could help is count on the browser's native functionality to remember entered data from cache. For that you would need to use input fields in a form, but in that case you are..

A: Depending on cache

B: Depending on browser implementation of this feature

Comment: I edited it and i put the code in so you can see what we have

Comment: We can make a database, what would you recommend we do to move forward with that?